# how to align two buttons and an input type range?

Tags: javascript, html, css

well, currently i got this code:

```html
<button onclick="zoomOut()">-</button>
<input id='zoom' type='range' value='10' min='0' max='20'></input>
<button onclick="zoomIn()">+</button>
```

this is only a part of all code, but all works good except button+input interface.

as u can see they are not in a regular line, i want to take button a bit up position or input a bit down position, but after try to modify all propierties i know, nothing works right, some ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried adding any CSS code to change the position of the `button` elements? (such as `margin-top`?)

Answer (score 4):

I've added the `vertical-align` property to `zoom` and assigned it the value `middle.`

```css
#zoom{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="zoomOut()">-</button>
<input id='zoom' type='range' value='10' min='0' max='20'/>
<button onclick="zoomIn()">+</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

for every object you need to align, in this case:

```css
body > *{
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="zoomOut()">-</button>
<input id='zoom' type='range' value='10' min='0' max='20'></input>
<button onclick="zoomIn()">+</button>
```

anyway i suggest you to wrap these three objects in a container